# ld: library not found for -lSystem error when linking for Apple Silicon

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly, arm, ld

xcode is Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Mac OS is Ventura 13.5

Command I am running:
ld hello.o -o hello -l System -syslibroot 'xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path' -e _main -arch arm64

The linker produces the error ld: Library not found for -lSystem

I am playing with a simple hello world program written for Apple Silicon Assembler. the source file is hello.s. The object file is hello.o I get the "ld: library not found for -lSystem error.
The results of the xcrun command above is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk

The System library file is: libSystem.dylib
I have found that file here: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib

Trying that path for the System library doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I do see this seems to be attached to the iphone os simulator? Should I find another copy of this library in a MacOS directory?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, so I will share it here for the next person that searches. In the sample code that I found, the reference to the main routine was _main. Changing this to something else, such as _start and then using the -e _start fixes the problem. Seems that ld has an issue with _main in newer MacOS versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).